# Variable Height In Bootstrap Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

My apologies if this has been answered before. I did search and found a few threads on this issue but am still struggling to get it working. I am hoping for a solution specific to my code.

I currently have a bootstrap grid system and have extra dead space beneath each of the landscape oriented pictures.

I want to have the space between images (vertically) to be the the same regardless of their height. My images are either 900px x 558px or 558px x 900px.

I imagine this layout function to be similar to Pinterest.

HTML (I've removed 2, 3 and 4):

```
<div class="pages section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pages-head">
            <h3>PORTFOLIO</h3>
            <div class="underline"></div>
            <h7> BRIDAL MAKEUP </h7>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <ul class="simplefilter">
                <li class="active" data-filter="1"><p>BRIDAL 1</p></li>
                <li data-filter="2"><p>BRIDAL 2</p></li>
                <li data-filter="3"><p>BRIDAL 3</p></li>
                <li data-filter="4"><p>BRIDAL 4</p></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="filtr-container">

                    <!-- bridal gallery 1 photos -->

                    <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="1">
                        <a href="../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-1.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-1.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

                     <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="1">
                        <a href="../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-2.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-2.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="1">
                        <a href="../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-3.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-3.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s6 filtr-item col-pd" data-category="1">
                        <a href="../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-4.jpg" class="image-popup"><img class="responsive-img" src="../img/portfolio/bridal/gallery_1/bridal_gallery_1-4.jpg" alt="sample image"></a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- end bridal gallery 1 photos -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end portfolio single -->
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 70%;
}

.container .row {
  margin-left: -0.75rem;
  margin-right: -0.75rem;
}

.row {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row .col {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.row .col[class*="push-"], .row .col[class*="pull-"] {
  position: relative;
}

.row .col.s6 {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    'use strict';

     // portfolio filter container
    $('.filtr-container').filterizr('filter', '1');

    // portfolio filter
    $('.simplefilter li').click(function() {
        $('.simplefilter li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    // portfolio image-popup
    $(".image-popup").magnificPopup({
        type: "image",
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: "mfp-fade"
    });

});
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is the layout you're instantiating Filterizr with in the options.

As long as there is variable height in your images you should use the sameWidth or packed layouts, to achieve a pintrest-like layout.

To achieve this you need to instantiate your Filterizr like this:

```
$('.filtr-container').filterizr({ layout: 'sameWidth' });
```

or

`$('.filtr-container').filterizr({ layout: 'packed' });`